# problems when tring to run python code as a windows service, using win32serviceutil,

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-services, python-3.8, pywin32

I met some problems when I tried to run my python code as a win32 service.

I was requested to write some python codes to prevent my classmates using web browsers for fun.

My idea was:

- Service start in certain periods of time
- Search for tasknames of browsers
- Then kill it
- Loop every few seconds

I currently dont have much time to systematically learn this library so I found a code and modified it

That code is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hBj78Vr22p/)

And my code is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BpXSBjx2Nh/)

The problem is when i coding in PyCharm with Python38 it gave no errors but when I tried to install&start it as a win32 service it stopped with code 1.

Event inspector showed an error:

```
Python could not import the service's module 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[username]\PycharmProjects\worms\test_service\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import win32serviceutil
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32serviceutil'
```

So what should i do next or do you guys have better solutions?